# How to get Native Federation to work load node.js app?

Tags: typescript, express, socket.io, angular16, angular-module-federation

https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/native2/libs/native-federation/README.md

So I am trying to make a Native Federation that has an angular application as the shell and loads a node.js app as a remote. The node.js app runs successfully on port 2002. I just can't get the shell to interact with it at all.

federation.config.js file

```
module.exports = withNativeFederation({

  name: 'game',

  exposes: {
    './Game': './projects/game/src/nodeapps/testgame/app.js',
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

  skip: [
    'rxjs/ajax',
    'rxjs/fetch',
    'rxjs/testing',
    'rxjs/webSocket',
    // Add further packages you don't need at runtime
  ]
  
});
```

federation.manifest.json

```
{
    "mfe1": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.json",
    "game": "http://localhost:2002/remoteEntry.json"
}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

// Add this import:
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/native-federation';

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },

  // Add this route:
  {
    path: 'flights',
    loadComponent: () =>
      loadRemoteModule('mfe1', './Component').then((m) => m.AppComponent),
  },

  {
    path: 'game',
    loadComponent: () =>
      loadRemoteModule('game', './Game').then((m) => m.app.js),
  },

  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
  },

  // DO NOT insert routes after this one.
  // { path:'**', ...} needs to be the LAST one.
];
```

I am guessing the issue is that I don't have the right syntax to load where my node.js is hosted, and its not loading a module but more an http request, but I really can't find an example of someone doing what I am attempting.

Any help would be appreciated.